django consistently fails to load css on deployment
I was deploying a simple django application to kubernetes and encountered the error of not being able to load css and js. I have tried several times to change the dockerfile,change the volume path, but I can't fix it.

I've spent 1 week still not finding the error, am I overlooking something?
Here are my files and code
main/settings.py
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
env.read_env(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'main/.env'))

....
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/app/static'

Dockerfile
# Use the official Python image as the base image
ARG ARCH=
FROM ${ARCH}python:3.12-slim as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --default-timeout=100 --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . .

FROM ${ARCH}python:3.12-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app /app
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages /usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/bin /usr/local/bin

EXPOSE 8080

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Specify the command to run your Django app
CMD ["gunicorn", "--workers=3", "--bind=0.0.0.0:8080", "main.wsgi:application" ]


deployment.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: static-files-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 0.5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: /mnt/static-files
  storageClassName: do-block-storage
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: static-files-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 0.5Gi
  storageClassName: do-block-storage
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: auth-db-config
data:
  DB_NAME: auth
  DB_HOST: patroni.default.svc.cluster.local
  DB_PORT: "5432"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: auth-db-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  DB_USER: Y***************y
  DB_PASSWORD: S***************4=
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: auth
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: auth
          image: xxxx.com/auth/app:latest # my private registry
          env:
          - name: DB_NAME
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: auth-db-config
                key: DB_NAME
          - name: DB_HOST
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: auth-db-config
                key: DB_HOST
          - name: DB_PORT
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: auth-db-config
                key: DB_PORT
          - name: DB_USER
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: auth-db-secret
                key: DB_USER
          - name: DB_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: auth-db-secret
                key: DB_PASSWORD
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          volumeMounts:
            - name: static-files
              mountPath: /app/static
      volumes:
        - name: static-files
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: static-files-pvc
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: auth
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: auth
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: auth
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080


ingress-nginx.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: web-ingress
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/issuer: letsencrypt-nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - xxxx.com
    secretName: letsencrypt-nginx
  rules:
  - host: xxxx.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /static/
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: auth
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: auth
            port:
              number: 80

Container static file is exist:
root@auth-7794b4dc86-h7ww4:/app# ls /app/static
admin  rest_framework
root@auth-7794b4dc86-h7ww4:/app# 


have you done collectstatic ?

Refer to this Document which will help you to resolve your issue. Also go through this Stack Link which might be helpful.

@IsraaSalameh yes, i running python manage.py collectstatic in contianer

@PranayKumarKyasala I read the link and tried changing STATIC_ROOT to the absolute path of the volume in settings. But it doesn't work.

Delete every last reference to any sort of volume from this setup.  In the Pod spec, delete the volumes: and volumeMounts:, delete the PersistentVolumeClaim, and delete the PersistentVolume.
What's happening in this setup as you have it is that Kubernetes is taking the content from the /mnt/static-files on the host directory of each node – possibly different files on each node, most likely an empty directory – and then mounting that over /app/static in the container.  That hides any static files that might have been built into the image (hopefully from the COPY . . Dockerfile line), which would include your base Javascript and CSS assets.
I'm guessing you're trying to reproduce a Docker Compose oriented setup that attempts to use a Docker named volume to share the static files into an HTTP proxy container.  This isn't reliable even in Docker (it might not work if the proxy has files in that directory too, it will ignore updates to the underlying image, it only works with one kind of storage).  In your Kubernetes setup you're using an Ingress object to forward HTTP requests on /static/ to your container, which serves its own static assets, and that's often a better approach.

I am new to kubernetes. I feel a bit abstract about the description in the last paragraph. Do I understand it correctly: should I recreate a pod dedicated to static files and then change the static's service of ingress-nginx to this pod?

I deleted all the relevant resources, deleted the drinking of pvc,pv and volums volumeMounts in deployment.yaml and rekubectl apply -f deployment.yaml, then went into the container and executed python manage.py collectstatic, and as before it generated the css and js correctly. But still getting the same error.

You shouldn't need to do anything special for static files – you do not need a volume or a separate container or anything else.  The Django static-file handling should work fine for you.  The "go into the container" step seems problematic and you might be missing a step in your Dockerfile if you need to generate these files.

The dockerfile I got from searching the web is almost identical to mine, except that it doesn't have a staged build. But despite adding RUN python manage.py collectstatic  to my dockerfile, it still seems to be inaccessible. I'm now guessing that the problem may not be with django but with ingress-nginx?It can't access /app/static?

The Kubernetes Ingress controller can't access files at all, only forward requests on to some Service.  You don't need a dedicated route for your static assets if you have a match-all route that forwards to your application.

I've been trying to use nginx and django app in the same pod, using them on the same shared volume. But it still doesn't help.
